# Python launch google chrome on Android

Tags: android, python-2.7, google-chrome

I need to launch Google Chrome that display this page "http://www.google.com", on an Android machine with a with a Python script.

Comment: I have tried webbrowser.get('Google-chrome').open_new('http://www.google.com')

Answer (score 0):

You can use Embed Python 2.7 (3.2 and others) interpreter, for more details look into following link
http://code.google.com/p/android-python27/